# How to position a control generated by code in a panel?

Tags: c#, controls, panel

Im trying to position a Circular progress bar generated by code in a panel but i dont know how did it
I have a button to generated this control i do it in the form but i cant in the panel.

im using this code but i dont found the correct function

`circularPB.Location = panel1.;`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please include details about what framework you are doing this in, ex. a web app in ASP or blazor, a desktop framework like winforms, WPF, MAUI, Xamarin, etc

Comment: The coordinates you give will be relative to the upper left of the PARENT CONTAINER. So if `circularPB` was INSIDE `panel1`, then you could put it at (10, 10) using `circularPB.Location = new Point(10, 10);`.

Comment: Did you add it to the panel with `panel1.Controls.Add(circularPB);`?